# Limit colorbar to specified range

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to generate a filled contour plot in Matplotlib (`v3.1.0`) and highlight only a narrow range of values by limiting the colour range. In my current approach, the colourbar extends to the full range of values, and I want to limit this range to `(vmin, vmax)` and use `extend` to indicate that the colours are clipped. See the following example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
y = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = X**2 + Y**2

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1)
CS = ax.contourf(x, y, Z.T, levels=200, vmin=0.9, vmax=1.1, cmap="RdBu")
cb0 = fig.colorbar(CS, ax=ax, ticks=[0.9, 1.0, 1.1], extend="both")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: Contourplot with colourbar]

As you can see, the colourbar is not limited to `(0.9, 1.1)`, and does not `extend` either (the arrows do not appear). Any ideas?

Comment: You take 200 levels between 0 and 2. But you distribute the colors only between 0.9 and 1.1, so the rest will be monochrome. Probably you want to limit the levels to this smaller range as well.

Comment: Is there a way to simply cut off the excess levels from the colourbar (so anything above 1.1 and below 0.9)?

Comment: No. (One might be tempted to try something like `cb0.ax.set_ylim(0.9,1.1)`, but the result would look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1i5mz.png))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the levels to the range of values you're interested in.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
y = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = X**2 + Y**2

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1)
CS = ax.contourf(x, y, Z.T, levels=np.linspace(0.9,1.1,51), 
                 vmin=0.9, vmax=1.1, cmap="RdBu", extend='both')
cb0 = fig.colorbar(CS, ax=ax, ticks=[0.9, 1.0, 1.1], extend="both")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]